# CXF: Can not generate WSDL at runtime

Tags: java, cxf, classloader, apache-camel

I am trying to publish a camel CXF webservice using **Code-first approach**. Ido not get any error if I run the webservice URL on browser.
[image]

**ApplicationContext**

```
<cxf:cxfEndpoint id="routerEndpoint" address="http://localhost:15080/PORTAL/webservices/"
            serviceClass="webservice.CamelCXFInterface"
            />
```

**ERROR**
But I get following exception when I try to add a new SOAP UI project with its WSDL url:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/AsyncContext
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.<init>(AbstractHttpConnection.java:157)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.<init>(AsyncHttpConnection.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector$ConnectorSelectorManager.newConnection(SelectChannelConnector.java:325)
```

I did add `geronimo-servlet_3.0_spec-1.0.jar` which has AsyncContext class but still server is not able to recognize it.

Comment: Can you double check that the jar is correctly deployed with your application ? Restart the server (if possible)

Comment: Yes. I did that. But still have same issue. Could it be conflicting with some other jar?

Comment: I am using https://code.google.com/p/jar-explorer/downloads/detail?name=jarexplorer-0.7-BETA.jar&can=2&q=  when I want to check if some jar contains some classes. It can be use to check conflicts or find missing jar.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Camel are you using?

How did you deploy the camel route?

Can you double check the Jetty version that you used within Camel and CXF?